# TypeError: this.props.AddNewHero is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know this kind of question has been posted a lot on StackOverFlow but in my code, I couldn't find the error why my code doesn't work.

I try to create a new Hero in my AddHero.js component (this is a child component) and update that new Hero to the state in App.js (parent component). However I get the error showing that TypeError: **this.props.AddNewHero is not a function**

Here is my code:

**AddHero.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddHero extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            Id: 0, Name: "", Dob: new Date(), Stocked: true, Price: 0
        };  
    }

    onNameChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            Name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onDobChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            Dob: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onStockedChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            Stocked : e.target.value
        });
    }

    onPriceChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            Price : e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSave(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const newHero = {           
            Name: this.state.Name,
            Dob: this.state.Dob,
            Stocked: this.state.Stocked,
            Price: this.state.Price
          };

        this.props.AddNewHero(newHero); //The error is here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Add hero</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Name </label>
                        <input type="text" onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Dob </label>
                        <input type="date" onChange={this.onDobChange.bind(this)} defaultValue={new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Stocked </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onStockedChange.bind(this)} ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Price </label>
                        <input type="text" onChange={this.onPriceChange.bind(this)}></input>
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.onSave}>Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddHero;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AllHeroes from './components/Hero/AllHeroes';
import AddHero from './components/Hero/AddHero';
import EditHero from './components/Hero/EditHero';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    Heroes: [
      { Id: 1, Name: "hero1", Dob: new Date("1-1-2017"), Stocked: true, Price: 1.50 },
      { Id: 2, Name: "hero2", Dob: new Date("5-31-2018"), Stocked: false, Price: 2.50 },
      { Id: 3, Name: "hero3", Dob: new Date("2019"), Stocked: true, Price: 3.50 },
      { Id: 4, Name: "hero4", Dob: new Date("4-20-2010"), Stocked: false, Price: 4.50 },
      { Id: 5, Name: "hero5", Dob: new Date("12-31-2018"), Stocked: true, Price: 5.50 },
    ]
  }

  GetAllHeroes() {
    return this.state.Heroes;
  }

  AddNewHero(newHero) {
    const id = this.state.Heroes.length + 1;
    newHero.Id = id;

    this.setState({
      Heroes: [...this.state.Heroes, newHero]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">

          <Link to={'/'}>Home </Link><br />
          <Link to={'/AllHeroes'}>All Heroes </Link><br />
          <Link to={'/Add'}>Add </Link><br />

          <Switch>
            <Route path='/AllHeroes' component={AllHeroes} />
            <Route path='/Add' component={AddHero} AddNewHero={this.AddNewHero} />
            <Route path='/Edit/:id' component={EditHero} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router >
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass props with a `Route` like that, you should use the `render` prop for this purpose.

```
<Route
  path="/Add"
  render={(props) => <AddHero {...props} AddNewHero={this.AddNewHero} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `react-router` and count on it to drill down props and this is not happening. You should try to pass a wrapped component, instead of the original one in App.js.
The following should work:

```js
<Route path='/Add' component={() => <AddHero AddNewHero={this.AddNewHero} />}
```